# creating instances of a class that has several readonly properties

Tags: vb.net, properties, immutability, instantiation

What is an elegant way to create and initialise instances of a class that has several readonly properties? Passing all values in a constructor would not be very convenient.

The purpose is that instances are immutable after initialisation. However if the constructor is not used for initialising all the property values, then how can the readonly properties be changed from another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are readonly so that they can't be modified after construction. This behavior is by design.

If you want to reduce the parameter count have a look at the [Parameter Object Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject)

Comment: The class itself already serves as a ParameterObject !
But like the pattern description suggests, using multiple constructors for different common use cases and/or mutator methods could be useful ideas. +1 for the pattern.

Comment: And I guess I could divide the class in a bunch of ParameterObjects that group related parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices

1. Create a public sub to update the Variables after initialization, or add the update to another section of code within the private methods of the class.
2. You use reflection to update the private Variables value.

The 1st way is by far the best option, the seconds is a hack.